# pygame key.set_repeat not working

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to pygame and I am trying to make pong in order to learn it. I am trying to make smooth controls so that holding down an arrow will work, but it is not working right now.

```
import sys, pygame
pygame.init()
size = (500, 350)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
x = 1
xwid = 75
yhei = 5
pygame.key.set_repeat(0, 500)
while True:
    vector = 0
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                vector = 4
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                vector = -4
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,255,255),(x,size[1] - yhei,xwid,yhei),0)
    pygame.display.update()
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    x += vector
    if x <= 0:
        x = 0
    elif x >= size[0] - xwid:
        x = size[0] - xwid
```

why does this not work for holding down the left or right arrows?

Comment: What do you want to do? Moving a picture or?

Comment: If you want to learn more about pygame, I recommend you to do some small games. And here is a good example:[Beginning Game Programming for Teens with Python](http://www.raywenderlich.com/24252/beginning-game-programming-for-teens-with-python)

Comment: if you look at the code everything works fine. It moves when pressed, what doesn't work is the repeating, which is all I am asking

Comment: @KillConsole: the examples from your link don't include what I am trying to dowith the `set_repeat`

Answer (score 9):

```
pygame.key.set_repeat(0, 500)
```

If you set the `delay` parameter to `0`, key repeat will be disabled. The [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#comment_pygame_key_set_repeat) isn't quite clear about that:

> **pygame.key.set_repeat()**
>   *control how held keys are repeated*
>   `set_repeat() -> None`
>   `set_repeat(delay, interval) -> None`
>
> When the keyboard repeat is enabled, keys that are held down will generate
>   multiple pygame.KEYDOWN events. The delay is the number of
>   milliseconds before the first repeated pygame.KEYDOWN will be sent.
>   After that another pygame.KEYDOWN will be sent every interval
>   milliseconds. **If no arguments are passed the key repeat is disabled.**
>
> When pygame is initialized the key repeat is disabled.

Emphasis mine.

You could set the `delay` to `1`, and it would work as expected:

```
pygame.key.set_repeat(1, 10) # use 10 as interval to speed things up.
```

---

But note that you should not use `set_repeat` and the `pygame.KEYDOWN` event to implement movement. If you do, you won't be able to observe real single key strokes, since if the player presses a key, a whole bunch of `pygame.KEYDOWN` events would be created.

Better use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed). Have a look at his minimal example:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((680, 460))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# use a rect since it will greatly 
# simplify movement and drawing
paddle = pygame.Rect((0, 0, 20, 80))

while True:

    if pygame.event.get(pygame.QUIT): break
    pygame.event.pump()

    # move up/down by checking for pressed keys
    # and moving the paddle rect in-place
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]: paddle.move_ip(0, -7)
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]: paddle.move_ip(0, 7)

    # ensure the paddle rect does not go out of screen
    paddle.clamp_ip(screen.get_rect())

    screen.fill((0,0,0))    
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), paddle)
    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know what do you mean. Try this:

```
import sys, pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
size = (500, 350)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
x = 1
xwid = 75
yhei = 5

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    key_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key_pressed[K_LEFT]:
        x -= 4
        if x <= 0:
            x = 0
    if key_pressed[K_RIGHT]:
        x += 4
        if x >= size[0] - xwid:
            x = size[0] - xwid

    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,255,255),(x,size[1] - yhei,xwid,yhei),0)
    pygame.display.update()
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

try it !

```
  pygame.key.set_repeat(1,500)
```