# constant movement in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

This is my first pygame code not much, pretty straight forward. When I want to move my player it works but I would love to have the movement steadily. Like when I press left I want it to move left. At the moment I have to press every time the left button so the player moves to the left. Do you have any suggestions how to do that?

```
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()

window_size = ( 400, 400 )

white = ( 255, 255, 255 )

class Player():
  image = pygame.image.load( 'foo.png')
  rect = image.get_rect()

player = Player()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode( window_size )

done = False

while not done:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      sys.exit()

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
      if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        move = (-10, 0 )
        player.rect = player.rect.move(move)
      if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        move = ( 10, 0 )
        player.rect = player.rect.move(move)
      if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        move = ( 0,-10 )
        player.rect = player.rect.move(move)
      if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        move = ( 0, 10 )
        player.rect = player.rect.move(move)

  screen.fill( white )
  screen.blit( player.image, player.rect )

  pygame.display.flip()
```

**Edit** My approach to Aarons answer:

```
while not done:

  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      sys.exit()

  pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
  if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    move = ( 2, 0 )
    player.rect = player.rect.move(move)
  if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    move = ( 2, 0 )
    player.rect = player.rect.move(move)
  if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
    move = ( 0,-2 )
    player.rect = player.rect.move(move)
  if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
    move = ( 0, 2 )
    player.rect = player.rect.move(move)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [Sloth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25501071/4323812) on a similar question. It seems that you have two potential approaches, either making use of set_repeat or get_pressed.

**set_repeat**

> When the keyboard repeat is enabled, keys that are held down will generate multiple pygame.KEYDOWN events. The delay is the number of milliseconds before the first repeated pygame.KEYDOWN will be sent. After that another pygame.KEYDOWN will be sent every interval milliseconds. If no arguments are passed the key repeat is disabled.
>    [Source](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.set_repeat)

Something like this would do the job:

```
# set_repeat(delay, interval)
pygame.key.set_repeat(1, 10) 
# A delay of 0 disables the repeat.
# The lower the interval, the faster the movement would be.
```

**get_pressed**

> Returns a sequence of boolean values representing the state of every key on the keyboard. Use the key constant values to index the array. A True value means the that button is pressed.
>   Getting the list of pushed buttons with this function is not the proper way to handle text entry from the user. You have no way to know the order of keys pressed, and rapidly pushed keys can be completely unnoticed between two calls to pygame.key.get_pressed(). There is also no way to translate these pushed keys into a fully translated character value. See the pygame.KEYDOWN events on the event queue for this functionality.
>   [Source](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed)

Something like this should fit into your code nicely:

```
pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if pygame.K_LEFT in pressed:
   # move left
if pygame.K_RIGHT in pressed:
   # move right
```

Solution implemented into @ZedsWhatSheSaid's code, also added PEP-8 formatting:

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

window_size = (400, 400)

white = (255, 255, 255)


class Player():
    image = pygame.image.load('foo.png')
    rect = image.get_rect()

player = Player()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(window_size)

done = False

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pygame.K_LEFT in pressed:
        move = (-10, 0)
    player.rect = player.rect.move(move)
    if pygame.K_RIGHT in pressed:
        move = (10, 0)
    player.rect = player.rect.move(move)
    if pygame.K_UP in pressed:
        move = (0, -10)
    player.rect = player.rect.move(move)
    if pygame.K_DOWN in pressed:
        move = (0, 10)
```

Comment: I think the second suggestion here is more correct than my answer which basically does the same thing but requires you to write the state management in Python rather than using the existing PyGame interface.

Comment: Brilliant, I did get through implementing it so I'll share my code on my answer anyway, I'm unfortunately not able to currently test so in the event there's a bug feel free to edit/remove my addition.
I'm happy you got it to work though, enjoy your journey in Python!

Comment: Please, never ever use `set_repeat`. [It sucks.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18998475/142637)

Comment: in newer versions of pygame it's `if key[K_LEFT]:`

Answer (score 3):

You could track both `KEYUP` and `KEYDOWN` events then store a pressed state for each of the keys you are tracking.

Now instead of moving the player whenever the user presses a key, you test the state of the key to see if it is pressed and apply movement to the player if it is.

As a simplified example:

```
pressed_keys = {
    'left': false,
    ...define other keys...
}

while not done:

    # Check for key events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                pressed_keys['left'] = True
            ...check other keys...

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                pressed_keys['left'] = False
            ...check other keys...

   # Move the player
   if pressed_keys['left']:
       ...move player left...
```

Comment: Your answer is really awesome too, because one get the idea on how this work, but I marked Aarons answer as accepted because it was more *'pygamic'* :P

Comment: It's better to just use ´get_pressed´ to get the state of the pressed keys instead of creating your own dict to store the state. With your code, you have to add 4 unnecessary lines of code to your game for each key you're interessted in.